# Concrete5 - unique block on every page

Tags: block, concrete5

I have a block that displays the number of clicks on the page it is installed.

I want to display that block on every page.

I have tried creating a `stack` and then including that stack into a global area. The problem is that when the stack is included it includes **the same block** on every page.

So instead of having different blocks on every page, I have the same block on every page. That results in counting the clicks on **all** pages instead of only the current one.

How can I include a block on every page, but each having an unique `ID` as it has when added manually?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There's no way to have a unique block on every page without adding it manually. Even if you make it a "page type default", you'll end up with a shared block ID until you make the first edit (at which point it'll get it's own ID). And if you hardcode into the page's PHP code, it won't have a block ID at all.

With that being said, I don't know why you need a unique block ID. Obviously, each page is going to have a unique ID. So your block should be able to store clicks (I'm not sure exactly what you mean here, but it's probably irrelevant) against the page ID (collection ID in c5 parlance), and retrieve it against that, too.

*Edit:*
Considering your comment, and based on my understanding of what you're trying to do, there's no reason why you can't combine the block ID (which will, as you say, be duplicated across pages, but will be different on each block ON a page) and the page ID. So if you place two blocks in a stack, they'll get IDs 1 and 2. They'll have IDs 1 and 2 on *every* page the stack is own. So when you're trying to "record" whatever data they product, you combine the bID with the cID to get 1-103 and 2-103, and 1-4719, etc.

*Edit 2:*
So if your difficulty isn't so much "keying" the data, but physically storing the data, then see jordanlev's comment below. You won't be using the `$btTable` table as that's keyed off the bID. Instead you'll use `db.xml` to create a new table which can take your new key, and whatever other data you want to store. It's then your responsibility to query and update it with `Loader::db()`. See his block, or see the core's "survey" block for examples of how to manage your own db table.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I said "number of clicks" just to make the question easier to read, I actually do something else. How can I implement the block so that it retrieves data based on the page it is, but **also** be able to put multiple blocks on a single page? If I only retrieve based on pageID I can't have multiple blocks on the page.

Comment: Well, the question may have been easier to read, but it's harder to help you without knowing exactly what you're trying to do.... So, you want to be able to attach the block to the page, multiple times (either in stacks or page type defaults, but not code), and you want to be able to configure/log/differentiate/whatever each of these block instances separately? A combination of block id and page id will do it. See my edit.

Comment: Yes, but the question is not how do I retrieve the data, but how do I store it? I mean, where do I get the "1-103" and "1-4719" mentioned in your edit from? Each block only has one row in the database, how can I store additional data? Eg: store for bID and pageID value X. It seems like I somehow need to insert a new row containing this two keys (bID and pageID) and the value X.

Comment: It sounds like you're trying to store front-end data (the # of clicks) in the block's "back-end" table (the one specified by the block controller's `$btTable` variable). What you might want to do instead is put the block into a package, then have a single package-wide table (defined in the package's db.xml file, not the block's db.xml file) and store your click data there. For an example of how something like this works, check out my free Email List Signup addon - http://tinyurl.com/78yr825 - it has a "submissions" table at the package level to store all form submissions in one place.